# Python: combine columns then rows by group

Tags: python, list, pandas, tuples, pandas-groupby

I have this dataframe:

```
In [182]: data_set
Out[182]: 
  name  parent  distance  rank
0  x     aaa      10        1
1  x     bbb      5         1
2  x     fff      3         2
3  y     aaa      2         2
4  y     bbb      10        1
5  z     ccc      8         2
```

I want to reshape it to:

```
  name          Combined
  x     ('aaa',10,1),('bbb',5,1),('fff',3,2)
  y     ('aaa',2,2),('bbb',10,1)
  z     ('ccc',8,2)
```

Then I wanted to convert it into `dataframe 3x2` with two columns `name` and `combined`. 
I was thinking to use `zip` or `group` but those return different outputs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First combine your columns to `tuple`, then `groupby` to `list`.

```
df['combined'] = df[['parent', 'distance', 'rank']].apply(tuple, axis=1)

res = df.groupby('name')['combined'].apply(list).reset_index()

print(res)

  name                                  combined
0    x  [(aaa, 10, 1), (bbb, 5, 1), (fff, 3, 2)]
1    y               [(aaa, 2, 2), (bbb, 10, 1)]
2    z                             [(ccc, 8, 2)]
```

Comment: Thank you @jpp. your solution is working fine and and the output is what I exactly wanted!

Answer (score 1):

By using `groupby` and `apply`

```
df.groupby('name')[['parent','distance','rank']].apply(lambda x : x.values.tolist())
Out[14]: 
name
x    [[aaa, 10, 1], [bbb, 5, 1], [fff, 3, 2]]
y                 [[aaa, 2, 2], [bbb, 10, 1]]
z                               [[ccc, 8, 2]]
dtype: object
```

Comment: Thank you @Wen! your solution is working fine, but it returns "series" instead of dataframe.